# plt.tricontour looks weird?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 vectors of variables, x, y and z. I wanted to see how z changes depending on x and y. As I have 1D lists I have used plt.tricontour to plot the graph:

```
plt.tricontour(x, y,z, 1000, linewidths=0.5,cmap=cm.coolwarm)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I am really confused as to what is happening in the right bottom corner of the graph? I am not sure why I am not getting gradient of colours as I do in the left top corner but get these lines instead. I would appreciate if anyone has any ideas!

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tricontour` is supposed to draw lines. So what you see in the lower right corner is expected. The upper left corner looks unexpected. The reason is that the desity of lines is so high that you don't see them as lines but as a filled area.

Depending on your desired outcome you can

- use  `tricontourf` instead of `tricontour`
- use less levels
- use levels which are unequally spaced, i.e. more levels for lower data values than for higher values; this can be done by supplying an array or list as fourth argument to `tricontour` or `tricontourf`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll test the tricontourf out. I am just a little bit confused as I created a grid of x and y variables between 0.-1.with an increment of 0.1, and the lower corner looks as if I have less data points for that area, I am starting to think I am misunderstanding the graph?

Comment: Actually, sorry, would this weird behaviour be because I have 100 x,y values and I am using 1000 density of lines? Sorry, you did suggest this in your reply.

Comment: The number of lines you see is not determined by the density of points on the grid, but by the dynamic range of the **`z` values**. In regions where the `z` data is shallow, there are less lines then in regions where it is steep. However, you may of course change that by suppling unequally spaced levels e.g. something like `[0,0.05, 0.1,..0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9]` in case the `z` values are between 0. and 1.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense now.